# Call function after dom element load

Tags: angular, typescript

so I have a div element (canvas) that's being loaded behind an asyncpipe. When that canvas loads, I need to fill it with a function called `loadChart()`. I need the function to be called after the canvas element loads. I have searched quite a bit and was not able to find much except that I need to use a directive which implements `AfterViewInit` and use a `ngAfterViewInit()` to call the function I need after the div element has loaded. I may be (most likely) am approaching this the wrong way, but I would like some guidance towards the right direction if anyone has some ideas.

**Home.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/authentication/auth.service';
import { ComputationService } from '../../services/computation/computation.service';
import {map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  units: Observable<Array<any>>;
  unitsData: Array<any>;
  occupancy: number;
  vacancy: number;
  chart: Chart;
  constructor(private route: Router, public authService: AuthService, private computationService: ComputationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadCharts();
  }

  loadData() {
    this.units = this.authService.getData().pipe(
      tap((results: any) => {
        if (results.success === true) {
          this.UnitsData = results.data;
          this.occupancy = Math.round(this.computationService.findOccupancy(this.unitsData) * 10000) / 100;
          this.vacancy = Math.round(this.computationService.findVacancy(this.unitsData) * 10000) / 100;
        }
      }),
      map((results: any) => results.data)
    );
  }

  loadCharts() {
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['Occupied', 'Vacant'],
        datasets: [{
          data: [this.occupancy, this.vacancy]
        }]
      },
      options: {}
    });
  }
}
```

***home.component.html***:

```
<div *ngIf="(units | async) as units; else loading">
  <mat-card-content>
    <canvas #canvas></canvas>
    <h2>{{occupancy}}% occupied</h2>
    <h2>{{vacancy}}% vacant</h2>
  </mat-card-content>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the loadCharts method inside a tap after your getData.pipe(..., map, tap((val) => loadCharts)? Using ViewChild doesn't work because it is called before your dataService observable emits.

Comment: I’ve tried calling it where I call my computation service and it doesn’t load because it loads after it emits the observable.

Comment: I didn‘t mean to just call it in the ngOnInit after the first method but rather to combine your first observable with the second to make sure the second observable is called once the first emitted. Since you only need to call a method the tap operator should be sufficient.  Observable1.pipe(tap(...),map(...),tap(call loadCharts here))

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is presumably that at the time of your `ngAfterViewInit` your units observable hasn't emitted a truthy value yet. Because of this your canvas isn't available yet.

Instead of `@ViewChild` you can use a `@ViewChildren` that provides you with a `QueryList` of canvas elements. The QueryList has a `changes` observable. With it, you can react in the moment when the canvas is added to your view.

Another option would be to extract the synchronous stuff to a further component where you will have your canvas available `onViewInit` and you can use the ViewChild as you did already.

Comment: Sorry for the question, how would I go about implementing that in my code?

Comment: `@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;` should become   `@ViewChildren('canvas') canvases: QueryList<HTMLCanvasElement>;`
Somewhere (onInit I assume) you can subscribe to `canvases` and then react when the QueryList becomes non-empty. More [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Comment: That's what I currently have. I meant how would I use it with ViewChildren?